# Creating a Rich Text File (rtf) in Python

Tags: python, pdf, ms-word, rtf

I have a question about generating Rich Text output in Python. I had a decent amount of experience processing data with Python and writing to .csv/.txt files for opening in Excel.

I'm working on a project to generate a patient report from a Python program that has stripped all the diagnoses/items of interest out of a database. Basically, I have a list of diagnoses and currently just write it to a .txt file with no formatting. Ideally, the program will apply formatting to the text (e.g. diagnoses are in bold, criteria for each diagnosis is a bullet point under the bold point). The gold standard would be if I could somehow create a PDF of the report w/ headers and footers as well.

Any ideas on how this could be possible? Is Python blatantly the wrong choice for this?

Comment: It probably wouldn't be hard to write your own rudimentary RTF exporter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format

Comment: The accepted answer is for creating a PDF, so it would be good to change the title to creating a PDF.
Because the answer brings no info to someone who actually wants to create a RTF and not a PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out PyPDF for creating nicely formatted PDF files with Python: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/06/05/creating-pdfs-with-pyfpdf-and-python/

Here's a simple demo of how you could use the package to create a pdf:

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Helvetica", size=12)
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="HEADER", ln=0, align="C")
pdf.cell(0, 10, txt="11/8/18", ln=0, align="R")
pdf.output("example.pdf")
```